# How to show HTML5 datalist dropdown on button click using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular8

I am using an input box with HTML5 `datalist`. Once the user enters some text and clicks the search icon/button, it fetches data which I want to show as dropdown/datalist suggestions. How can I do this? Here is my code (I use Angular 6):

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="group">
      <input #name list="browsers">
      <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
      </datalist>    
      <button (click)="editName()">Edit</button>
  </div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild("name") nameField: ElementRef;

  editName(): void {
    this.nameField.nativeElement.focus();
  }

}
```

Comment: Once user click the button I want to show the dropdown, instead of user again click on input box.

Comment: please share component.html as well

Comment: Is this for Angular or AngularJS? Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: @NagaSaiA I have used templete not templeteURL,so no separate compnent.hmtl file. 
template: `
    <div class="group">
      <input #name list="browsers">
      <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
      </datalist>    
      <button (click)="editName()">Edit</button>
  </div>
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and array to do this

```
import {Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

text:string='';
options =['Internet Explorer','Firefox','Chrome','Opera','Safari'];
show=this.options;
  editName(): void {
    this.show= this.options.filter(x=>x.includes(this.text)); 
  }
}
<div class="group">
      <input [(ngModel)]='text' #name list="browsers">
      <datalist id="browsers">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of show" value="{{opt}}">
      </datalist>    
      <button (click)="editName()">Edit</button>
  </div>
```

[Click to view example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seartch-datalist?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)